# how to shift controls from one tabpage to another at runtime c# Windows

Tags: c#

I am using windows form. in which there is a tab control and three tab pages. in the first tab page i have a combobox. which loads some data from the database. I need to use this combobox in tabpage 2 and 3 . when the user select tabpage 2 the combobox should be visible. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions that I can think of.

1. Move the combobox out of the tab control. Since all the tabs use the same combobox anyway then it serves a non-tab specific functionality. Design wise, this makes the most sense as you will avoid redundancy between the 3 comboboxes.
2. Create 3 separate comboboxes for each tab and make each combobox reference a same collection. Don't forget to update the selected item of all the 3 comboboxes once an item is chosen by the user. Also take not that this will require more code changes than the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put your combobox on first tab. Then add an event handler to the SelectedIndexChanged event of your tab control and put this code in it:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
}
```

The `Add` will automatically remove it from the tab where it has been before. Of course you have to provide free space on all tabs where the combobox is located.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, using the VB code: `TabStrip1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(*controlname*)` to switch, but once it's off the original page and on to the new one, switching back to the original tab doesn't seem to work.
Just discovered that using `*controlname*.BringToFront` brings it on top again.